# How to create custom embed block in gutenberg wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Can someone please help me out here.

How can i create a custom embed block in WordPress(Gutenberg blocks), the block should ask the user the URL of the video to embed and some few options like auto play, after the user clicked the embed button it should display the video on the block.

I have already created a plugin and a basic block that allows a user to enter content on it and display it in front-end. Now i want to customize my block to allow video embeds.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the existing blocks and go from there (embed blocks are not the easiest block to start with however.)

- [gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src/embed](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src/embed)
- [gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/embed/core-embeds.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/embed/core-embeds.js)

You could start by trying to copy and paste to code to a new block, and get it running in the first step. ([create guten block](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block/) is really a good starting point for beginners). Then you could slowly start to alter things and to build your custom block from that.